# How to provide OpenGL context of empty QML Item for 3rd party render?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2

My application contain 3rd party code, which paints something using OpenGL. Only I can do is to provide full-screen surface for it and mouse/touchscreen events. Say I can create full-screen-sized `Item` and leave it for that 3rd-party render. The render emits some signals for me (maybe from arbitrary thread, by means of `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`) to update the view. How to block QML to paint into the context temporarily?

How described above can be implemented? Is it technically possible to create such a workflow?

Is there more wise way to achieve desired. Maybe using of FBO would be better?

Can I do this asynchronously? I.e. that render have its own message quque into separate thread.

Comment: The [Qt Quick Scene Graph](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html) documentation page describes various options for the integration. That will help to make the question more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look on QQuickFramebufferObject.

The way it works:

You create a subclass and instanciate it in QML. You should override its

```
Renderer *QQuickFramebufferObject::createRenderer()
```

You create your own subclass of Renderer http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickframebufferobject-renderer.html

All the code you put inside its void `Renderer::render()` will affect the FBOItem and be rendered to the screen. Qt is in charge to bind your FBO.

Now if you need to call for modification in the UI you call the `void Renderer::update()`.

Your third party renderer should call this method when he needs to draw but all your opengl methods (glDrawArrays ...) should be written inside the render function of the Renderer. Qt bind your FBO before accessing this method. Maybe your QQuickFramebufferObject should listen to your ThirdParty signals and modify (via some states, or std::functions) the render method of its Renderer components and call for an update.

Here are some good examples

http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/05/11/integrating-custom-opengl-rendering-with-qt-quick-via-qquickframebufferobject/